# How to "bound" to parameters in TypeScript, making one type "depend" on other type?

Tags: typescript, types, parameters, type-inference

Let me explain:

- `arg1` must be of `Type1` or `Type2`
- `arg2` must be of `Type1.options` (if `arg1` is `Type1`) or `Type2.options` otherwise

```js
create(arg1: Type1 | Type2, arg2?: any) {}
```

It's possible to define this "bound" in TypeScript?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) declaration to infer the dependency like this:

```
function create<T extends (Type1 | Type2)> (arg1: T, arg2?: T['options']) { ... }
```

You can also create an alias like `type ArgType = Type1 | Type2` to simplify the generic constraint:

```
function create<T extends ArgType> (arg1: T, arg2?: T['options']) { ... }
```

Comment: What if T.options is not always "T.options", but available as TOptions (say)?

Comment: If they're independent types you're going to need to elaborate how they're related. That's not the same question.

Comment: Even if the original types are set up as `T.options`, I don't think this solution will work as written because the type parameter passes only the type meaning of `T`, not the namespace meaning.  One would have to do something like make `options` an actual property in the type `T` (an optional property so as not to interfere with normal use of `T`) and then use `T["options"]`, or alternatively do something fancy with conditional types.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for an [overloaded function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads):

```
function create(arg1: Type1, arg2?: Type1.options);
function create(arg1: Type2, arg2?: Type2.options);
function create(arg1: Type1 | Type2, arg2?: Type1.options | Type2.options) { ... }
```

Do note that the last signature (the "implementation signature") is not one of the overload signatures and should be broad enough to cover all of the overload signatures.  You'll sort out the actual arguments in the body of the function.

Comment: Wow. That's cool... and verbose :) So I need to define each combination of arg1 and arg2... and in the end, make the "union" of all of them?

Comment: Yes, unless you want to get really fancy with conditional types to look up the proper type of the second argument based on the first.